# Acces userinput from kivyMD costum user input

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

I was looking through the documentation kivyMD docs and saw this neat example [Example](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/dialog/index.htm). However, where is the user input stored? Suppose we wanted to get the city name and print it to the console. Does anybody know?

**Custom content class.**

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog

KV = '''
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "City"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "Street"


MDFloatLayout:

    MDFlatButton:
        text: "ALERT DIALOG"
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .5}
        on_release: app.show_confirmation_dialog()
'''


class Content(BoxLayout):
    pass


class Example(MDApp):
    dialog = None

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self):
        if not self.dialog:
            self.dialog = MDDialog(
                title="Address:",
                type="custom",
                content_cls=Content(),
                buttons=[
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="CANCEL",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    ),
                    MDFlatButton(
                        text="OK",
                        theme_text_color="Custom",
                        text_color=self.theme_cls.primary_color,
                    ),
                ],
            )
        self.dialog.open()


Example().run()
```

[picture of screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xTKEK.png)

Comment: You may find the following posts helpful. [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72005145/kivymd-how-to-get-value-from-a-dynamic-text-fields), [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70381500/pass-input-value-to-dialog-and-send-to-screen), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71222346/python3-kivymd-mddialog-get-itemconfirm-text-value) etc.

Comment: As the comment has been deleted (NOT by me), to make it relevant let me tell you that I tried to encourage you to give it a try all by yourself before even asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily get the contents of a `TextField`, by giving it an `id`.

```
<Content>
    orientation: "vertical"
    spacing: "12dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    height: "120dp"

    MDTextField:
        hint_text: "City"
        id: city
        on_text_validate: root.get_city() #this just runs the get_city function if the user hits enter, this is not necessary
```

And then in the Content class:

```
    class Content(BoxLayout):
        def get_city(self):
            city = self.ids.city.text
#pulling the content of a TextField based on its id
            print(city)
```

And boom thats it, you have stored the contents of the TextField in a variable and you can now do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Sadly the ids don't seem to work for me. But I can see many people have the same problem with calling them. something about they don't get updated: anyways I will try to get it to work. Otherwise, I just have to open a new thread and ask about the id issue. Thank you!